# Date And Time Validation Error For Edittext In android

Tags: android, xml, uidatepicker

Hello I have given validation to date and time in android but when i am not selecting date it will show the error message but after selecting date from datepicker it again shows the error how to solve it here is my code

```
public class ProfileDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String description, str_requirement, str_date, str_time, str_noofperson, str_address;
    TextView txt_description;
    EditText et_requirment, date_pick, time_set, et_no_of_person, et_address_service;
    Calendar calendar;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    int Year, Month, Day;
    Button btn_submit;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_details);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        description = extras.getString("description");
        txt_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtservicedetails);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarforprofile);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        et_requirment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_requirement);
        et_no_of_person = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_noofperson);
        et_address_service = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_serviceaddress);
        date_pick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_dateof_visit);
        time_set = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_time);

        btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        Day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setTitle("Need-Hlp");
        txt_description.setText(description);
        //date_pick.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentfromprevious = new Intent(ProfileDetail.this, NavigationDrawer.class);
                intentfromprevious.putExtra("description", description);
                intentfromprevious.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intentfromprevious.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                intentfromprevious.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intentfromprevious);

            }
        });



        date_pick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(ProfileDetail.this, Year, Month, Day);

                datePickerDialog.setThemeDark(false);

                datePickerDialog.showYearPickerFirst(false);

                datePickerDialog.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#009688"));

                datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date From DatePickerDialog");

                datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerDialog");


            }
        });
        time_set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(ProfileDetail.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        time_set.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, true);
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();

            }
        });


        //////Submit button onclicklistener
        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (et_requirment.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    et_requirment.setError("Requirement cannot be blank");
                    et_requirment.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if (date_pick.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    date_pick.setError("Date cannot be blank");

                    //date_pick.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if (time_set.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    time_set.setError("Time cannot be blank");
                    //edittext_phone.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if (et_no_of_person.getText().toString().toString().equals("")) {
                    et_no_of_person.setError("No of person cannot be blank");
                    //edittext_phone.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if (et_address_service.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    et_address_service.setError("Address cannot be blank");
                    //edittext_Password.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }


                if (!et_requirment.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && !date_pick.getText().toString().equals("") &&
                        time_set.getText().toString().trim().equals("") &&
                        et_no_of_person.getText().toString().trim().equals("") &&
                        !et_address_service.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileDetail.this, "You Request Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intentforlist = new Intent(ProfileDetail.this, NavigationDrawer.class);
                    intentforlist.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intentforlist.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    intentforlist.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intentforlist);
                }

            }
        });
    }

Here Is MY XML:

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-45.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/profile_details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/demo"

                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="16dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtservicedetails"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editText_requirement"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                                android:background="#fff"
                                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
                                android:gravity="top"
                                android:hint="Your Requirement"
                                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                                android:padding="6dp"
                                android:textColor="#000" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_dateof_visit"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:background="#fff"

                                android:hint="Date Of Visit"
                                android:inputType="date"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#000" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_time"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:background="#fff"

                                android:hint="Time Of Visit"
                                android:inputType="time"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#000" />

                            <EditText

                                android:id="@+id/et_noofperson"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:background="#fff"
                                android:focusable="true"
                                android:hint="No Of Person You Need"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:maxLength="2"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="" />

                            <EditText

                                android:id="@+id/et_serviceaddress"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:background="#fff"
                                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890/-,:"
                                android:focusable="true"
                                android:gravity="top"
                                android:hint="Service Address"
                                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                                android:maxLines="4"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/rounded_green"
                                android:text="Submit"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: are you getting error on button Click ? @dipaks

Comment: yes on button click@Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your date click hope it will works for you

```
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // your format
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());

                    date_pick.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
                }

            };
            new DatePickerDialog(this, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```